# What is wrong with my inputbox

Tags: vba, inputbox

```
Sub weewe()

Dim jjj As String

Do
    jjj = InputBox("Type in the correct password", "password")
Loop Until jjj = "Master" Or vbCancel

If jjj = "Master" Then

    sss = MsgBox("thats the correct password", vbOKOnly, "Password")

ElseIf jjj = vbCancel Then

    Exit Sub

End If

End Sub
```

the code works but why when i click cancel do i get an error 13? And how do I fix it?

Comment: how do i click cancel without getting that error?

Comment: `Loop Until jjj = "Master" Or jjj = ""`   `Inputbox` returns False/empty string if you press Cancel, not `vbCancel` (2)

Comment: I tried that before, and i still get the same error 13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub weewe()

    Dim jjj As String

    Do
        jjj = InputBox("Type in the correct password", "password")
    Loop Until jjj = "Master" Or jjj = ""

    If jjj = "Master" Then
        MsgBox "thats the correct password", vbOKOnly, "Password"
    ElseIf jjj = "" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

End Sub
```